# Building QT Android app: ..i686-linux-android-g++: No such file or directory

Tags: android, qt

I am building the first application in QT Creator, and came to the step I don't understand.

I have Mac, Android Studio is installed, Android SDK and NDK are installed using Studio. PATH to $ANDROID_NDK_ROOT is set manually.

My application compiles for Desktop without problems but trying to compile it for Android gives me this error:

```
/bin/sh: /Users/drob/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/x86-4.9/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/i686-linux-android-g++: No such file or directory
/bin/sh: /Users/drob/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-g++: No such file or directory
/bin/sh: /Users/drob/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-g++: No such file or directory
Project ERROR: Cannot run target compiler '/Users/drob/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-g++'. Output:
===================
/bin/sh: /Users/drob/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-g++: No such file or directory
===================
Maybe you forgot to setup the environment?
Error while parsing file /Users/drob/OneDrive/DEVEL/PROJECTS/QT_Projects/btchat/btchat.pro. Giving up.
```

I found that I should do the following steps, but I am scared to completely crash the system:
1. Install G++ (but what is this and how to install it on Mac properly)
2. Create G++ toolchain using NDK script (unfortunately too complicated for me. Some guide will be welcome)

What I also found out is that normally QT for Mac uses Clang compiler from XCode that I also have got installed. Should I somehow make QT Creator use that compiler instead of G++?

Sorry for questions that might sound silly but I am really lost at that point

Answer (score 0):

Using the trial and error method I found that it is practically impossible to make NDK r10e work with QT 5.9. I ended up installing latest NDK and latest QT (5.12.6)